# Displaying Markers on a Google Map in a Visual Studio Website

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project

I am using Visual Studio to create a website (Website project) that will allow a user to view a set of markers on a Google Map. I basically have a global static list of 'marker' objects, and each marker object has fields for the name, latitude, longitude, etc... I followed this tutorial (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld) which taught me how to include the map in the webpage, and then I also followed a second tutorial (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-projection-simple) which taught me how to add multiple markers to the map.

As I understand it, to include the map in the webpage, I was required to write a section of code in JavaScript. How can I have the map plot markers according to the data stored in my list (which is all coded in C#)?

Appreciate the help!

Adrian.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the C# to load a local version of the HTML / Javascript you need in a WebBrowser component?  And utilize a js function to read the markers from a txt file of some sorts.

Comment: I actually did some research, and found a hacky method that works. I guess it's similar to your suggestion. 

In brief, I stored all of the sensor information in a Data Table, and then I converted the entire table into a properly formatted JSON string. I stored that string in a HiddenField object. In the JavaScript section of the code, I retrieved the data holder with the document.getElementById() command, and then converted that into a Javascript object with the 'eval()' function. Then I could access all of my data just like it was still a table!

Comment: Credit goes to: Ravi Kant Srivastava. See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19396/Convert-ASP-NET-DataTable-to-JSON-to-use-a-DataTab